# How to resolve the decode failed issue when importing a report into Jasper server via the Jasper API

Tags: jasperserver

We were able to import the same report manually, and we did not receive any errors when doing so.

IMPORT API

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2mdr.png)

We received the following response when we called the import API. They supplied the ID and status in this response. We must check the status of our imported report depending on the ID right now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<state>
    <id>0fd7ad18-ea7b-4f64-9bba-3151ee246338</id>
    <message>Import in progress.</message>
    <phase>inprogress</phase>
</state>
```

We will call and check the status of the imported report using the above response ID.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNiHV.png)

We got the import.decode.failed error, when we import report by using the jasper API.

We request help in resolving this issue; if you have a solution, please share it with us; we will check.

Did we miss out on any parameters when calling the import API?